# CoreData not updated until application inactivates

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, cloudkit

I'm building a Macos CoreData+CloudKit app.

I first create my container by doing this:

```
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TestApp")
let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
description?.setOption(true as NSNumber,
                       forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
let remoteChangeKey = "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey"
description?.setOption(true as NSNumber,
                           forKey: remoteChangeKey)
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
})
```

I'm registering to receive remote changes by doing this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(fetchChanges),
            name: NSNotification.Name(
                rawValue: "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification"),
            object: persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        )
```

And in `fetchChanges`, I just reload my UI by

1. Fetching the data
2. Reloading my tableView

However, I found out that `fetchChanges` is never called until the application inactivates. I see this in the log as:

```
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver noteRecievedNotification:](40): <PFCloudKitThrottledNotificationObserver: 0x600003fb3fc0>: Got: NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification - 0
```

What I'm assuming is happening is when CoreData detects my window inactivates via the `NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification` event, it spawns a background task to fetch the remote `iCloud` data into the local store.

At that point, the `NSPersistantStoreRemoteChangeNotification` is received.

**My question is how do you force the local store to sync with `iCloud`?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible clues:

1. You need to activate "Background fetch" in the "Background Modes" of the target's Signing & Capabilities
2. This happened to me because I needed to sign in to iCloud again (I had a prompt in the Settings, but if you don't it's worth trying to sign out and sign back in)